# How to configure Enterprise Library formatters not to remove "new lines" from the logged message?

Tags: .net, enterprise-library, logging-application-block

How to configure formatters not to remove "new lines" from the logged message?

logAttribute.Message="@p1='aa'\n@p2='bb'"

I want to find in the log:

```
@p1='aa'
@p2='bb'
```

Not

```
@p1='aa'@p2='bb'
```

Comment: Please say which version you are using.

Comment: Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.dll - 4.1.0.0. But you don't understand: I need answer not question :) Unfortunately the answer I guess is: it is impossible in all versions, only using custom formatters.

Comment: I understand that the answer to your question may depend on which version you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a literal string and force the actual break. Not elegant, but will do the job.

Alternatively, write your custom formatter.